# Release apk file was not generating after building VS 2013 apache cordova

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, apache-cordova

I have worked on two days back vs2013 cordova application apk release file was generated in bin/release folder.but today i tried to build apk file bin/release folder is empty.i have choosen release configuration ,andriod, device on listbox Connected With real device via USB.file was not generating what am missing here? have any setting need to update here.?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you choose device it deploy the apk directly on the connected device ... try to `choose the emulator` (with the right sdk version for you) .. or build it not with VS2013 but with ionic and cmd (`ionic build android` ) and launch it in the folder of your app.

remeber if you do like this the folder where you fond the apk is not bin!!

hope it helps!!!

Comment: Yes You are correct sometimes when i build the application apk was not generated directly.release apk iit is always generated on my bin folder even if i connected the device.i am created apache cordova application am not using ionic. how can i build this command(ionic build android) ?

Comment: you can build it with cmd .. (windows shell) .. go in the folder where is located your application ... and type in the cmd ionic build android..and it build the apk for you